# In an Android Gradle build, how to exclude dependencies from an included jar file?

Tags: android, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

In my Android project, I use a library that comes as a jar. 
I include it in the dependencies section like so:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile files('libs/thethirdpartylibrary.jar')
    ...
}
```

I also want to use the okhttp library, which I include like this:

```
compile ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5')
```

(This particular version of okhttp depends on okio 1.6.0.)

The problem is that the thirdparty jar library depends on okio v0.9.0 and what's worse, bundles it.

As a result, I get a dex conflict error at build time.

I was able to resolve this by manually removing okio from the jar file and this seems to work. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in gradle.

My question: Can I remove bundled, transitive ( <- I hope I'm using this word the right way) dependencies from an included jar during build-time with gradle?

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply recreate the third party jar to remove the classes in it that you don't want?  I don't think gradle will allow you to select specific classes to exclude out of a file dependency.

Comment: In fact, that's what I'm doing right now. I just was wondering if there's a (simple) way to do this with gradle, so that I don't have to do this manually every time the vendor library changes.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this? Can you share your solution?

Comment: have you got the answer to this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Exclude the Group in the dependencies by using the below lines.

1.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

2.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile ("com.xxx:xxx-commons:1.+") {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
}
```

3.

```
configurations {
    runtime.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
}
```

Try this one.

[For more detail](http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/gradle-exclude-transitive-dependency-example)

Comment: 2. this syntax does not work with file-based jar files (AFAIK...)

Comment: 3. I don't think I want to do this since I actually do want to include one verson of the library -- I just don't want to use the one from the JAR

Comment: There are three options to exclude the dependencies,

Comment: I think it will be helpful for you

Comment: It doesn't really answer the core question though, which is: How to exclude an dependency from a JAR.

Comment: but it seems to remove it from everything, so that doesn't help me unfortunately ;-| Thanks for your efforts, btw!

Answer (score 1):

According to this discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/g1AiJM7PeVs, what you want to do is not possible.

The syntax suggested in the other answers is for "normal" Maven dependencies.