# How to fix google play service error

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, build.gradle

Today after updating the play services in root folder I'm facing the following problem . I'm confused how to fix this.

Can anyone please help me to fix this ?

This error is irritating a lot. I don't know where's the conflict. By the way why it's showing conflict while no versions are interrelated.

**Error** :

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is
>   being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0],
>   [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

**build.gradle** script :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



android {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "community.infinity"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}

}

 dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
})
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.adamstyrc.cookiecutter:cookie-cutter:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.allattentionhere:fabulousfilter:0.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.thesurix.gesturerecycler:gesture-recycler:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.oxoooo:touch-image-view:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
implementation 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.2.0'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation('com.google.guava:guava:23.4-android') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0")   {
    // Excludes the support library because it's already included by Glide.
    transitive = false
}
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.2'

}
```

Comment: Solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52696667/3333878

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One of your dependency is having different version of `com.google.android.gms`.

## Update

> Firebase dependencies are having independent versions unlike past. If
>   you have version conflicts then you can update your
>   `com.google.gms:google-services`. and start defining independent
>   version.

#### Update `com.google.gms:google-services`

> Go to top (project) level build.gradle and update `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `4.1.0` [or newer if available](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services?repo=bt-android-tools).

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' //< update this 
    }
}
```

#### Update Firebase dependencies to **[Latest Versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)**

Firebase dependency versions can be individual. So check **[Latest Versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)**.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3    //Analytics
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2    //Realtime Database
```

## Orignal Solution (Useful)

Ways to resolve:

1. **[Exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36103326/6891563)** `com.google.android.gms` from conflicted dependency.
2. Update that dependency **[if available](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)**.
3. Change your `com.google.android.gms` version as conflicted version.

#### Problem

how to see which dependency is using `com.google.android.gms`?

## 1. Solution by command

**For Android, use this line**

```
 gradle app:dependencies
```

**or if you have a gradle wrapper:**

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

where `app` is your project module.

Additionally, if you want to check if something is `compile` vs. `testCompile` vs `androidTestCompile` dependency as well as what is pulling it in:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration testCompile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration androidTestCompile --dependency <name>
```

## 2 Use these plugins

[Gradle View](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-view) is an Android Studio plugin that you can install and show dependency hierarchy.
[Methods Count](http://www.methodscount.com/plugins) is another plugin, it also shows dependency tree.

Comment: Methods Count has been shut down so it is not able to provide new or updated library method counts anymore.

Comment: Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.

Comment: Better to use latest version of firebase dependencies to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @Khemraj I get the same error when I try to include `play-services-analytics` and `firebase-core`. I need `play-services-analytics` for `CampaignTrackingReceiver` and `firebase-core` for `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`. There are more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514926/com-google-android-gms-internal-measurement-is-missing-in-google-play-services-1

Comment: Did you check which dependency is being duplicate?

Comment: @Khemraj `play-services-analytics` includes `play-services-measurement-base:16.0.0` and `firebase-core` includes `play-services-meausrement-base:16.0.2`. I am using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'` which is the latest version. I have `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1"` and `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"` which are the latest stable releases.

Comment: @Wouter you are not using latest version of play-services-analytic. Use `"com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3`

Comment: @Wouter You can check latest version. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/16.0.3

Comment: @Khemraj Thanks, that has resolved the issue. Unfortunately, I now have a different problem: "Program type already present: android.arch.core.util.Function". I'll need to investigate this.

Comment: Encountering a similar issue when using react-native-code-push. "Dependency failing: com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:5.1 -> net.minidev:json-smart@[1.3.1,2.3], but json-smart version was 2.3." This hasn't been resolved even with 4.2.0

Comment: Exclude did the job for me. 

{
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }

Answer (score 19):

Try this is working for me.

Add this in your `build.gradle` end of file

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

With google play service. Version 4.3.0

```
googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: With version 4.3.0 and above of Google Play services plugin, use
`googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true`

Comment: @Akshay I use the above code but i get 
ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true' not found.
can you suggest me why i coming

Comment: I use this approach but when I want to compile the project it says RecyclerView symbol is not found, and also this seems a weird approach

Comment: using this may lead to unexpected behaviour or even crashes as this unpredictable behaviour is what the "mentioned error" tries to warn us about and fails fast.

Comment: Just to make clear, add it in `app` level `build.gradle`

Comment: @hek there is no app level in build.gradle?

Comment: @sembilanlangit there is, that is the `build.gradle` where you put all your 3rd parties libraries in. It's usually named as `build.gradle (Module: projectname.app)`, last `.app` indicates that file is `app level gradle`. The other one is `project` level gradle, assuming you didn't have other module.

Answer (score 6):

Firebase Android SDKs [now have independent version numbers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html), allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.

Update the google play gradle plugin version to latest version, currently 3.3.0.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

and update the libraries to the [latest version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

```
Firebase Core   com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
Ads             com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0
Analytics       com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
App Indexing    com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0
Authentication  com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
Cloud Firestore com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
Cloud Functions com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0
Cloud Messaging com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
Cloud Storage   com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2
Crash Reporting com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2
Crashlytics     com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
Invites         com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.2
Performance Monitoring  com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.1.0
Realtime Database   com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0
Remote Config   com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2
```

Also as [reported](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) use at least the version 15.0.2:

> You will need to update the version of the latter dependency to 15.0.2. This addresses the issue where version 3.3.0 of the Google Services Gradle plugin reports: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2...

Comment: What do you mean by `use at least the version 15.0.2`?! For example there are some libraries that their latest version is `15.0.1`, such as `play-services-location:15.0.1`.

Answer (score 3):

For me i needed to update `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` to version `15.0.1` instead of `15.0.0`.

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"`

Comment: @holydragon at your app gradle file, under `dependencies`

Comment: still got this error for version 18.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Firebase components can now have independent versions (see latest release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

What is likely happening is one of your other dependencies is pulling in multiple versions of your com.google.firebase:* dependencies beyond your explicit dependencies onto

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
```

You may be able to solve this specific problem by moving your dependency of firebase-messaging to 15.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use core library component together with other firebase components:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I lost 4 days to this, here are the exact steps that worked for me:

```
cordova build android
```

delete platforms folder

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
cordova build android
ionic cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
ionic cordova emulate
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found my solution in this section 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180508

This indicates that not all firebase dependencies have the same version numbers for the current build. So you need to update each one independently. My final configuration looked like this:

> `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
>   implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2"
>   implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"`

Hope you can see the difference and new update as a result of google service plugin 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Solve the issue by following updates
in android project.properties

```
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.+
```

and in android cordova support google service -build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}

ext.postBuildExtras = {
  if (project.extensions.findByName('googleServices') == null) {
    // apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
    apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
    googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
  }
}
```

This may help you too.