# 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' conflicts with com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to use google map, but the dependency (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1) conflicts with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' .. can anyone help?
here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gamecodeschool.mapso"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

my top-level build file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
      }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: why am i only getting devoted , at least devote and help

Comment: You have to mention what's the error your getting at least so that people cane help, conflict can happen so many different ways

Comment: Can you post your app-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Thanks. What happens when you update `appcompat-v7` to `27.1.1`?

Comment: Almost, the same error

Comment: Just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157690/how-to-fix-google-play-service-error/50158079), which may be of interest. Can you also post your top-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Okay , i'll read it thanks a lot , i added the top-level build file

Comment: Add this to the `dependencies` section of your top-level `build.gradle` file: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: i added it , sadly i am still having the same error message , red line under 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' saying " all com.android.support librariesmust use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

Comment: this is the exact problem i am having, anything related to firebase is resulting in that conflict no matter what you add remove -

Comment: i just changed the version of appcompat-v7 to 26.1.0 and the targetsdkversion to 26 ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue when trying to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1`.

In the Terminal, if you look for the dependency tree by doing `./gradlew app:dependencies`, you'd get something that includes:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
```

Clearly, this causes the conflict and the way to resolve this would be switch to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0` instead.

Also, you will have to downgrade your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same suggestion as @Gaurav but instead of downgrading your support library, you can exclude a conflicting dependency from play-services.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
}
```