# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:9.8.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-sdk-2.3

I tried to implement google play services but I am getting this error 
Failed to resolve: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:9.8.0`

When I tried to install this, I encountered such a pop-up message could not find dependency `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:9.8.0'`

The features of the project as shown below::

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

Comment: What are the dependencies you are using in your build.gradle? Or are you depending onto play-services-stats directly?

Also note, Google Play services SDK is now served from maven.google.com (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and have been for over a year now.

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. The problem happenned because of this if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            details.useVersion('9.8.0')
        }

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I just added 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'' and I removed this part (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') { details.useVersion('9.8.0') }.... By the way I encountered with this problem from a react-native projects

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

On Tools>SDK Manager>SDK Tools 
Check if Google Play Services is enabled, if not you have to install that first.

Comment: Note, Google Play services SDK is now served from maven.google.com (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and has been for about a year now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest gradle dependencies for your project. For more information visit below link which will help you.

[Update Google Play ServiceDependenciess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157690/how-to-fix-google-play-service-error)