# ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I getting error like this when I tried to upgrade my plug-ins.I tried lot bu Unable to fix this.

**Gradle:**

```
private static void googleAndFirebase(configuration) {
//gcm
configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'

//Firebase libs
configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

//lib for map
configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

//google analytics
configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'

//map utils
configuration.implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5' 
}
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0.
5]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:16.0.6 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-m
easurement-base@[16.0.5], but play-services-measurement-base version was 16.3.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl@17.0.5
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics@16.0.6
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@16.3.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl@16.0.6
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.3.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@16.0.5
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl@16.0.6
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.7
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@16.3.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@16.3.0

For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
uild.gradle file
```

I have tried the solutions whats mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157690/how-to-fix-google-play-service-error) But my problem was not solved.

please let me know what's the exact issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As clearly mentioned in the firebase Document .

> configuration.implementation
>   'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

is proving google analytic

> We recommend starting with com.google.firebase:firebase-core, which
>   provides Google Analytics for Firebase functionality.

And you are also using .

> configuration.implementation
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'

It is causing that issue .Both are using google analytic . So you should use any one for analytic of your app .