# Ionic 5 when build fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

```
 BUILD FAILED in 13s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
/Users/khalid/Documents/projects/zaahib/zaahib_ionic/platforms/android/gradlew: Command 
failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property
```

'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at 
>      an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
>         1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be 
>      unknown.

```
  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 -> 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
  15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive 
  dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@15.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-places- 
   placereport@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@15.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@15.0.1

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info 
:app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle 
  plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { 
 disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50158079/5059916

Comment: Hi Khalid. In the beginning of your post, please show the code you think is causing the problem and the ask a question, such as, "How can i fix this?"