# Espresso Androidx compatable with v7 recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat, android-espresso, androidx

My app's Reyclerview is "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
And I use androidx's espresso.

I added dependencies to my gradle like below:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:' + rootProject.androidxLibVersion;
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:' + rootProject.androidxLibVersion;
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:' + rootProject.coreVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:' + rootProject.extJUnitVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:' + rootProject.runnerVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:' + rootProject.espressoVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:' + rootProject.espressoVersion
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:' + rootProject.espressoVersion
```

However, when I am trying to use

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions

    ...

RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(position)
```

It says

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: (is assignable from class: class
>   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the
>   screen to the user) Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131296674,
>   res-name=media_content_recyclerview, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440,
>   height=2384, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true,
>   has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true,
>   is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false,
>   is-selected=false,
>   layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@e32b046,
>   tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false,
>   x=0.0, y=192.0, child-count=15}"

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: If you're certain that you're using `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in the app and not `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`, then you need to change the dependencies not to use androidx to test in your gradle.

Comment: @Aaron It works, thank you.

Comment: @John - I am facing the same issue. Can you help me with the solution? I did not get what Aaron is trying to say.
I am using 
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
and 
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

Comment: @Vikash, As far as I remember, I excluded dependencies.
Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103299/in-an-android-gradle-build-how-to-exclude-dependencies-from-an-included-jar-fil